Rendering 招子庸‘s name into English?
I am looking for the most accepted way of rendering 招子庸's name into English. There seems to be some discrepancies:

Chiu Tsz-yung (In Cecil Clementi's translation)
Chao Tzu-yung (In Victor Mair's paper)
Ziyong Zhao (Google's (autogenerated(?)) translation)

Mandarin conventions would probably have it as Zhao Ziyong. Modern Cantonese conventions might have as Ziu Zi-jung (that doesn't seem right?).
I'm lost. What is the most common modern English rendition of his name?

Depending on your audience, Ziu Zi-jung is fine for Cantonese readers as it is the Cantonese pronunciation of 招子庸.

There is no "most common" so far, as his name only occurs in a handful of mostly linguistics papers. As the English-speaking/writing (linguistics/scholastic) audience becomes more familiar with the history of Cantonese writing, there may be a standard that emerges, or other factors may interact to reach a standard, or indeed no standard emerges.

答案已经在你给的链接中 https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E6%8B%9B%E5%AD%90%E5%BA%B8 明确给出了，可能你没发现。
招子庸 链接中提到：

1992年，学者Peter T. Morris亦再将招子庸的《粤讴》译为英文，收录97首粤讴，在香港大学出版社出版了《Cantonese Love Songs: An English translation of Jiu Ji-yung's Cantonese songs of the early 19th century》一书

I think render  招子庸's name in English should be Jiu Ji-yung.

I am also seeing "Jiu Ji-yung (招子庸, 1786–1847)" in Yeung's paper on the "Cantophone," as he calls it.

@Mou某  What is "Yeung" and "Cantophone" in your comment about ""Jiu Ji-yung (招子庸, 1786–1847)" in Yeung's paper on the "Cantophone,""?
